# rebase branch to squash history with merge commits

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have the following situation in my branch:
[image]

As you can see, another branch (green) was created from our main branch (red) some time ago, some commits where added and it was then merged back onto our main branch, which did not receive any commits in the mean time. Some more commits have been added to the red branch since then, so our Head is actually a little further to the left.

How would I go about rebasing this branch onto itself (the first commit all the way to the right) to squash it's commit history, including all the commits from the green branch into the red branch (so I actually only have on single branch left) ?

**EDIT**
I managed to solve it by soft resetting the HEAD back to e , squashing everything before, then soft resetting the branch to a, committing b, c and d onto a and then applying my stashed contents. Quick and worked like a charm!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *Squash* is not the right term, here. You want to *rebase*, not squash. Also, ideally for your question, you should indicate the names and tips of both branches on your commit graphs. Anyway, what you should do is checkout the branch of interest, then run `git rebase <SHA-of-commit-d>`.

Comment: It would be really helpful for git novices if you added a detailed, step-by-step, description of your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout a new branch based on commit `d`

```
git checkout -b RB d

                      main
                      |
                      V
a----------------e----f
 \              /
  b------c-----d
               ^
               |
               RB
```

rebase your `main` branch

```
git rebase main

                      main
                      |
                      V
a----------------e----f
 \              /
  b------c-----d----e'-----f'
                           ^
                           |
                           RB
```

switch back to your main branch and reset it to the rebased branch

```
git checkout main
git reset --hard RB

                           main
                           |
                           |
a----------------e----f    |
 \              /          V
  b------c-----d----e'-----f'
                           ^
                           |
                           RB
```

[git gc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) will clean up the commits `e` and `f` one day because they are not referenced anymore.

So your repository will looks like this one day

```
                         main
                           |
                           V
 a---b----c----d----e'-----f'
                           ^
                           |
                           RB
```

As long as git gc has not removed `e` and `f` you can restore them by using their commit id.

```
git checkout -b restored_main f
```

Comment: I will mark this as correct even though its not how i solved my problems :)

Comment: @Eisenhorn Maybe you can add your solution as an answer too. If it is a good answer you will get upvotes and if you missed something you will get comments. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try interactive rebasing with command:

git rebase -i Head~6

This will pop-up a notepad with last 6 commits. You would not need to change that just Save and Close. Your commit history should be fine after rebase completes.

Comment: This will not give me the option to include the commits from the green branch however.